# Update scope in directive and make available for next directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[plunker for code](https://plnkr.co/edit/aV65Nab9U9I6YlK2g4sY?p=preview)

There are two directive link with a element.
HTML

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="VehicleOriginalCost">{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleOriginalCost.QuestionData._text}}</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" id="VehicleOriginalCost" class="form-control" name="VehicleOriginalCost" ng-model="answers.VehicleOriginalCost" data-que-obj="questions[$state.current.name].VehicleOriginalCost.QuestionData" required text-control-dir cbq-dir number-only>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                    <span class="form-error" ng-show="submitted && DTOstep1.VehicleOriginalCost.$error.required">This field is required.</span>
                </div>
```

Directive are textControlDir and cbqDir.

selectControlDir directive sets value for the questions if there is any default value.
cbqDir directive should access updated value after selectControlDir and do operation.
But cbqDir do not have updated value.
I am getting  undefined in cbq directory when I pass ngModle in url.

Directive

```
function textControlDir()
{
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100,
        scope: {
          ngModel: '=',
          queObj: '='
        },
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(scope.ngModel))
            {
                scope.ngModel = scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
            }               
        }
    };
}

function cbqControlDir($http)
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 200,
            require: ngModel,
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        //http call 
       //url apc.php/ngModel          
            }
        };
    }
```

I tried to solve this using priority but no change.
please help me to find out how to get updated scope value in other directive.

If I remove selectControlDir, it works fine. But i don't want to remove, looking for solution how can i refresh/update scope here.

Issue is only on load no ton change. onchange it works fine because value is available in $scope.

Comment: is queObj a primitive value? if that so, wrap your value inside an object: it might be a "copy by value" problem.

Comment: queObj is object that have set of value require to setup quesytion. For now only scope.queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue is used here. This give default value if ngmodel do not have any value.